# Como acrescentar 1 segundo a uma data em Oracle?

Tags: banco-de-dados, query, oracle

Estou a tentar procurar numa tabela uma linha que tenha o start_date no segundo seguinte à data colocada.

```
 select * 
                    from    PAY_PERIOD
                    where   pay_period_schedule_id = 2 
                    AND  start_date = TO_DATE('2020-04-30 23:59:59','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + 1
                    AND DELETED = 0 
                    ORDER BY end_date desc;
```

Já tentei adicionar 1 como está no código mas nao funciona se eu tiver as variaveis das horas,minutos e segundos lá. DATEADD não existe para Oracle e já tentei somar com TO_DATE('00:00:01','HH24:MI:SS')

Eu quero que fique com a data 2020-05-01 00:00:00

Answer (score -1):

Mal publiquei a pergunta, fez-me luz... 
Vou deixar aqui para alguém que possa ter a mesma dúvida

```
select * 
                    from    PAY_PERIOD
                    where   pay_period_schedule_id = 2 
                    AND  start_date = TO_DATE('2020-04-30 23:59:59','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + interval '1' second
                    AND DELETED = 0 
                    ORDER BY end_date desc;
```

Comment: ou <data>+(1/86400)